# Php operator `break` doesn't stop while

Tags: php

Have a weird issue, `break` doesn't break while loop and keep rotating. Logically it should break the cycle and I set some output

```
    while ($c++ != 5)
    {
        // here is curl request, doesn't relevant so I have removed it 

        preg_match("!<.*?>(\S*)[^<>]*?{$to}<!", $resp, $result) ;
        //
        echo 'cnt = ' .count($result).'<br>';
        if(!count($result))
        {
            $amount = 0;
            echo 'sleep called';
            sleep(4);
            exit;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $amount = trim(@$result[1]);
            $amount = round($amount + $amount * $exchange_ratio, $precision);
            echo 'break happen<br>';
            break;
        }
    }
```

so output is

```
cnt = 2
break happen
cnt = 0
sleep called
```

So it skipped `break` and keep rotating. How so?

EDIT
works fine on my localhost so issue probably with php version?

Comment: Once something hits `exit;` it stops there and will not `continue;` - remove the `exit;`

Comment: True, but I guess the issue here is: why isn't the break after the echo of `break happen` (sic) jumping out of the while strucuter

Comment: Can you setup a minimal and isolated demo of the issue you are experiencing? I'm fairly certain the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be running this code multiple times: is there a second call to this script, or a second loop around this part? Look at my test code: it clearly breaks after the break:

> $ cat tmp.php

```
<?php 

$c = 0;
 while ($c++ != 5)
 {
     if(false) //just emulating you
     {
         $amount = 0;
         echo 'sleep called';
         sleep(4);
         exit;
         continue; //this will never be called by the way
     }
     else
     {
         echo 'break happen<br>';
         break; //this indeed breaks out of the while
     }
 }
```

`$ php tmp.php`
`break happen<br>$`

(the $ is the  next prompt, on the same line as I did not put in a newline :) )

Comment: Curious as of why someone considers this wrong.

Comment: Most probably because it's not a direct answer, but more or less just a rechalk of the existing script using your own variables illustrating default functionality. Which is totally fine, but is not a clear and concise answer as to why OP's code doesn't work. Not saying it should be downvoted, but ya know.. (fyi I did not downvote)

Comment: I disagree: its a proof of concept with an example-run of that a complete dumbed down version will behave as expected. So there must be something different in the OP's code. e.g.: it's proof the OP's code should not give the stated result

Comment: `So there must be something different in the OP's code`. Aye, indeed. Which is why this doesn't directly answer the question but more or less eludes to OP needing to debug something further, which is what the real answer should be. =)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think for this special case this answer is valid, becaue the error is not in the code the OP provided. Writing an answer based on guesswork is really not any better (imo).

Comment: @Yoshi Fair enough. =)